# Change time part of date with momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Hello i'm getting from datepicker onChange event this date eg.

```
2019-11-21T20:59:00.000Z
```

how i can change here just hour, minutes and seconds part so time part of the date?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`hour()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/hour/), [`minute()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/minute/), and [`second()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/second/) methods of `moment`

```
onChange = (event) => {
   const mmnt = moment(event);

   const hours = 1;
   const minutes = 1;
   const seconds = 1;
   return mmnt.hour(hours).minute(minutes).second(seconds).toDate();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var date = '2019-11-21T20:59:00.000Z';
console.log(moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
<!-- with hours, -->
console.log(moment(date).format('hh:mm:ss'))
console.log(moment.utc(date).format('hh:mm:ss'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the hours, minutes and seconds, simply use the add function in moment.js as shown. You can replace the parameter in `.utc()` to your date variable.

```
var date = moment.utc('2019-11-21T20:59:00.000Z')
        .add(20, 'seconds')
        .add(10, 'minutes')
        .add(3, 'hours')
```

To remove these units, a negative number will also work

Comment: It's interesting when i console log this i'm getting : 00:10:20 date part is no have

Comment: Oh, my bad, I thought you wanted the date out of the equation. This is the do with the format. I will update to have the whole date with the changed hours etc.

Comment: @user3348410 I have updated the answer, will provide the full date along with modified time units :)

Answer (score 0):

this gives you 24 hours time like this **20:59:00**

```
moment.utc('2019-11-21T20:59:00.000Z').format('HH:mm:ss')
```

this give you 12 hours time like this **08:59:00**

```
moment.utc('2019-11-21T20:59:00.000Z').format('hh:mm:ss')
```

using this you get hours minutes and seconds

Comment: This gives 7:59:00, which isn't correct when 20:59:00 is converted to a 12 hour clock

Comment: i'm not trying to get it i'm trying to change it

Comment: @user3348410 I have updated my answer to what you have requested (Changing the hours/minutes/seconds)

Comment: I change my answer please check @user3348410